# How do I split a string and keep the separators using python re library?

Tags: python, python-re

Here is my code:

```
import re
string = r"('Option A' | 'Option B') & ('Option C' | 'Option D')"
word_list = re.split(r"[\(.\)]", string)
-> ['', "'Option A' | 'Option B'", ' & ', "'Option C' | 'Option D'", '']
```

I want the following result:

```
-> ["('Option A' | 'Option B')", ' & ', "('Option C' | 'Option D')"]
```

Comment: No. I tried this: "([\(.\)])", and got this: ['', '(', "'Option A' | 'Option B'", ')', ' & ', '(', "'Option C' | 'Option D'", ')', '']
I want brackets included in the string, not separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to capture each parenthesis group:

```py
import re
string = r"('Option A' | 'Option B') & ('Option C' | 'Option D')"
pattern = r"(\([^\)]+\))"
re.findall(pattern, string)
# ["('Option A' | 'Option B')", "('Option C' | 'Option D')"]
```

This also works with `re.split`

```py
re.split(pattern, string)
# ['', "('Option A' | 'Option B')", ' & ', "('Option C' | 'Option D')", '']
```

If you want to remove empty elements from using `re.split` you can:

```py
[s for s in re.split(pattern, string) if s]
# ["('Option A' | 'Option B')", ' & ', "('Option C' | 'Option D')"]
```

---

How the `pattern` works:

- `(` begin capture group
- `\(` matches the character `(` literally
- `[^\)]+` Match between one and unlimited characters that are not `)`
- `\)` matches the character `)` literally
- `)` end capture group

Comment: Thanks for the answer and guidelines on the use of patterns.  Adding line `word_list.remove('')`  next to `re.split(pattern, string)` eliminated empty elements. Please update it in your answer as well.