# Split String with multiple delimiters and keep delimiters

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

I'm looking fo an elegenat way to split a string by multiple delimiters and keep the delimiters at which the string got splitted.

Example:

```
input_str = 'X < -500 & Y > 3000 / Z > 50'
split_str = re.split("and | or | & | /", input_str)
print split_str
>>> ['X < -500', ' Y > 3000',  'Z > 50']
```

What I want so get for `split_str` would be:

```
['X < -500', '&', ' Y > 3000', '/', 'Z > 50']
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68860035/how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators-using-python-re-library

Comment: Also, you are splitting on ```spaces```

Comment: `re.split(r"(and|or|&|/)", input_str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with parenthesis:

```
>>> split_str = re.split("(and | or | & | /)", input_str)
>>> split_str
['X < -500', ' & ', 'Y > 3000', ' /', ' Z > 50']
>>>
```

If you want to remove extra spaces:

```
>>> split_str = [i.strip() for i in re.split("(and | or | & | /)", input_str)]
>>> split_str
['X < -500', '&', 'Y > 3000', '/', ' Z > 50']
>>>
```